# JPnelのメソッド「addActionListener」の役割について（ユーザーインターフェース）

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで質問です。

#### 1点目

ActionLister 型のクラス menuItemActionListener でインスタンスオブジェクトを生成したのに、なぜその後、個々の item01~item06 それぞれに `item01~06.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);` をする必要があるのでしょうか？

インスタンスオブジェクトである menuItemActionListener の中で既に
`selected = (JMenuItem) evt.getSource();` と書いており、選択されたメニューアイテムを変数 selected に代入するというプログラムだと思います。そうであれば、その後、直接

```java
b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(selected==item01) 〜
```

とコードを書いてもいい気がします。なぜなら `if(selected==item01)` で、selected がitem01（02~06) かどうかを boolean で判定しているためです。

なのに、なぜその前に `item01~06.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);` を入れる必要があるのでしょうか？

#### 2点目

`selected = (JMenuItem) evt.getSource();` はどういう意味でしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

**実行環境**
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

---

**全体のソースコード**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RateK extends JFrame {
  int n;
  JMenuBar mbar = new JMenuBar();
  JTextField f0 = new JTextField("");
  JButton b0 = new JButton("実行");
 
  JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Input a number and press the button.");
  JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Foreign Currency→to JPY"); 
  JMenu menu2=new JMenu("JPY to→Foreign Currency");
  JMenuItem item01 = new JMenuItem("USD to JPY");
  JMenuItem item02 = new JMenuItem("CNY to JPY");
  JMenuItem item03= new JMenuItem("Euro to JPY");
  JMenuItem item04 = new JMenuItem("JPY to USD");
  JMenuItem item05 = new JMenuItem("JPY to CNY");
  JMenuItem item06= new JMenuItem("JPY to Euro");
  JMenuItem selected;

  boolean a=false;
  boolean b=false;boolean c=false;boolean d;boolean e;boolean f;
 // boolean[]t=new boolean[6];
 
  

  public RateK() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setTitle("Please select Currency");
    setLayout(null);
    
    
    add(f0); f0.setBounds(100, 50, 50, 30);
    add(b0);b0.setBounds(150,50,50,30);
    mbar.add(menu1);mbar.add(menu2);setJMenuBar(mbar);
    menu1.add(item01);menu1.add(item02);menu1.add(item03);
    menu2.add(item04);menu2.add(item05);menu2.add(item06);
   
    add(l1);l1.setBounds(50,140,300,100);
    //pack(); 
    setSize(600, 400);
   
   ActionListener menuItemActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               
                // 選択されたメニューをセット
                selected = (JMenuItem) evt.getSource();
              
            }
        };
        item01.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
        item02.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
        item03.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
        item04.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
        item05.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
        item06.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);

    
    
    b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(selected==item01){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
        
            Dollar d1=new Dollar(n);
           Double d2=d1.Ex();
            l1.setText(n+"USDは"+d2+"円");}
        else if(selected==item02){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
            //l1.C1(n);
            Other c1=new Other(n);
            Double c2=c1.Ex2();
            
            l1.setText(n+"人民元は"+c2+"円");}

        else if(selected==item03){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
              
              Other c3=new Other(n);
              Double c4=c3.Ex3();
              
              l1.setText(n+"ユーロは"+c4+"円");}

       else if(selected==item04){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                
                Other c4=new Other(n);
                Double c5=c4.Ex4();
                
                l1.setText(n+"円は"+c5+"ドル");}

       else if(selected==item05){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                  
                  Other c5=new Other(n);
                  Double c6=c5.Ex5();
                  
                  l1.setText(n+"円は"+c6+"人民元");}

        else if(selected==item06){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                  
                    Other c6=new Other(n);
                    Double c7=c6.Ex6();
                    
                    l1.setText(n+"円は"+c7+"ユーロ");}

              
        
        else{return;} 
            
    
        }
      });

      
}


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new RateK().setVisible(true);
    
  }


  
  
  static class Dollar{
   int d=106;
  
   Double dl;Double n;

   public Dollar(Double n){
     this.n=n;

   }

   public Double Ex(){
    return dl=d*n;
   }

  }

  static class Other {
     Double cn;
     int c=15;
     int d=123;
     double e=0.0094;
     double f=0.0667;
     double g=0.0081;
     Double n;
     public Other(Double n){
       this.n=n;
     }
     
     public Double Ex2(){
      return cn=c*n;
      
     }

     public Double Ex3(){
       return cn=d*n;
     }

     public Double Ex4(){
      return cn=e*n;
    }

    public Double Ex5(){
      return cn=f*n;
    }

    public Double Ex6(){
      return cn=g*n;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: 1. タイトルは **具体的なもの** を心がけてみてください。「～について」は、結局何をしたい・分からないがはっきりしない書き方です。ヘルプの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考に / 2. コードが「自分で書いたもの」なのか、「誰か別の人が書いたもの」なのかもなんだかはっきりしない印象です。例えば、過去の質問での回答を参考にしたのであれば、それらも分かるように書いておいたほうが読み手に親切だと思います。

Comment: コードは自分で書いたものです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item01オブジェクトと、menuItemActionListenerオブジェクトだけがあるとします。

item01オブジェクトで何かAction（クリックされたりとか）が起きたら、どうなると思いますか？

２つのオブジェクトの間には何の関連付けも無いので、menuItemActionListnerオブジェクトにイベント(Actionが起きた事)が知らされる事はありません。

```
selected = (JMenuItem) evt.getSource();
```

と書かれていたって、イベント(evt)が無いのですから。

２つのオブジェクトを連携して動作するためには、item01オブジェクトで何かactionが起きたら、menuItemActionListenerが感知して処理してね。

```
item01.addActionListener(menuItemActionListener);
```

という設定が必要なんです。